# Exchange Web Services (EWS) client doesn't work on server, but works locally

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

We have a simple service that uses EWS 2.0 to connect to an Outlook mailbox and process email in a shared mailbox (yup, I know :))... so...

We created a domain user and gave it full rights to the mailbox. I'm specifying the WebCredentials, and for accessing the shared mailbox, I new up a Folder object with the mailbox name and using StreamingNotifications to watch the inbox.

All works fine on my PC.

We tried installing it on a server and we get a 401 access denied. If I go to that machine and telnet to the EWS server on 443, it lets me in, so its not a firewall issue. Like I said, I can run the app on my PC, so the mailbox and exchange are configured to let me connect.

Do I need anything else open? Any ideas what's generating the 401?

I can post code if necessary, but like I said, it works on my PC and on the server I can telnet to the EWS on 443.

On the server, I'm running the app with my domain account logged in and a command prompt.

How do I debug further?

Comment: 401 means you can get through on the port but there is some authorisation issue. Can you use office 365 through a browser in the server? You might find there's a whole load of security hardening on the server.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid is there any way to see to what the error is? I'm not too familiar with Office 365, do I need to install anything? They wouldn't let me install anything like that on a server. Or is it more of a just put the server name in a browser app?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid -- finally found the issue... it didn't like the domain\username format... it wanted username, password, domain format.

Comment: Great to hear it. I'm sure everyone would really appreciate it if you posted some specifics because I can tell google is going to find this post a lot, and it would be frustrating to find this without a concrete answer